# Is schema.rdfs.org dead? What alternatives exist?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, semantic-markup, schema.org, json-ld

[schema.rdfs.org](http://schema.rdfs.org/) is still linked from the [schema.org documentation page](http://schema.org/docs/documents.html) as the source for structured representations of schema.org data.  They used to scrape the site daily, but now it appears that the most recent update was in April 2014.  I found a link on their site to the [GitHub project with all the scraping code](https://github.com/mhausenblas/schema-org-rdf/tree/master/scrapers), and could run it as needed, but I would rather access a web service or static representation if a current one exists.

### What is my best option for retrieving up-to-date schema.org semantic metadata?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about site maintenance for schema.org.  You should probably ask on a forum for that site.

Comment: This is off-topic for a few reasons: (i) if there's a more up-to-date site, then this is resource request (which can obviously get old and "go bad";  a resource doing that is the premise of this question); (ii) it's probably too broad, since it asks about what options are out there; and (iii) it's primarily opinion based since it asks about which option is best.

Comment: duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/29905/is-schemardfsorg-dead-what-alternatives-exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On http://schema.org/docs/datamodel.html it says:

> The canonical machine representation of schema.org is in RDFa:
>
> [schema_org_rdfa.html](http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html)

It seems to include the [latest additions](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html).